# Prevent Encryption (Krypto) Of Url Paramaters in IBM Commerce Server 6

Tags: java, commerceserver

Hi we are using IBM Commerce Sever Moving from one view to another using via code like below.

```
protected void prepareResponse(){
...
String returnUrl = "www.example.com/aNewPage.jsp?aUrlParameter=123&anotherParameter=654"
...
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(returnUrl);
sb.append("&storeId=").append(commandContext.getStoreId());
sb.append("&langId=-1");
responseProperties.put(ECConstants.EC_REDIRECTURL, sb.toString());
responseProperties.put(ECConstants.EC_VIEWTASKNAME, ECConstants.EC_GENERIC_REDIRECTVIEW);
}
```

The url we are ending up at is www.example.com/aNewPage.jsp?krypto=ABCDF0LotsOfRandomCharacters
unfortunitly due to 3rd party intergration we have javascript looking for the unencryptped form of the url parameters and of couse it cannot decrypt the krypto parameter.

This behavour is as per the [documentation](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/websphere/commerce/54/en/ProgrammersGuide.pdf):

> ```
> Flattening input parameters into a query string for HttpRedirectView
>
> All input parameters that are passed to a redirect view command are flattened
> into a query string for URL redirection. For example, suppose that the input
> to the redirect view command contains the following properties:
> URL = "MyView?p1=v1&p2=v2";
> ip1 = "iv1"; // input to orginal controller command
> ip2 = "iv2" ; // input to original controller command
> op1 = "ov1";
> op2 = "ov2";
> Based upon the preceding input parameters, the final URL is
> MyView?p1=v1&p2=v2&ip1=iv1&ip2=iv2&op1=ov1&op2=ov2
> Note that if the command is to use SSL, then the parameters are encrypted
> and the final URL appears as
> MyView?krypto=encrypted_value_of“p1=v1&p2=v2&ip1=iv1&ip2=iv2&op1=ov1&op2=ov2”
> ```

Now the question:
How do I prevent these url parameters being encrypted?

Comment: Wow so few IBM Junkies on SO. 6 views on an unanswered question after 16 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters that are encryted are controled by the NonEncryptedParameters node in wc-server.xml. Adding the url parameters you want to stay in clear text to that node mean they don't get encrypted.

```
<NonEncryptedParameters display="false">
    <Parameter name="storeId"/>
    <Parameter name="langId"/>
    <Parameter name="catalogId"/>
    <Parameter name="categoryId"/>
    <Parameter name="productId"/>
</NonEncryptedParameters>
```

I found the answer on [IBM's Forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14287163&#14287163) and a link detaling the use of the [NonEncryptedParameters Node](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/tdc_encryparam.htm) which talks about doing this for cache purposes.